# How to debug webpack 'Executing webpack failed with exit code 0' in Nativescript-Vue

Tags: webpack, nativescript-vue

I tried updating a Nativescript-Vue project from NativeScript version 6.2.1 to 6.5.0 (following the [upgrade instructions](https://docs.nativescript.org/releases/upgrade-instructions)). Trying to run the project via "tns run android" fails, giving very little information as to why:

```
File change detected. Starting incremental webpack compilation...

webpack is watching the files…

Executing webpack failed with exit code 0
```

I don't know much about webpack but 0 should be success, right? Anyway, I figured whatever is causing the build to fail might be an error that gets swallowed somewhere. So I tried debugging by adding dozens of console.logs to webpack-cli:s code (in node_modules/.bin/webpack) to see if something weird is happening. But I couldn't find anything (nor did I really know where to look). There is only one place where process.exit() is explicitly called with no arguments (the exit code defaulting to 0) but that call is never made in my case.

I'm wondering if there are some ways to debug webpack in a NativeScript-vue project that could be useful? I added `stats: 'verbose'`  and `bail: true` to the config but that didn't do anything.

Here are the parts of package.json that I thought are relevant:

```
  "nativescript": {
    ...
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.5.0"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.5.0"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "@vue/devtools": "^5.3.3",
    "nativescript": "^6.5.0",
    "nativescript-vue": "^2.5.1",
    "tns-core-modules-widgets": "^6.5.0",
    ...
  }
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~1.5.1",
    "nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.1",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.1"
    ...
  },
```

---

[Edit:] The compliation failure seems to be because of compatability issues between NS and NativeScript-Vue, as NativeScript-Vue 2.5.1 has an older version of NativeScript as its dependency.

Still, I would like to know if there are ways to debug webpack to get to the source of what causes a compliation failure.

[Edit2:] Updated to NS-Vue 2.6.1 that supports NS 6.5.0 but the problem persists.

Using the --log trace option yields some additional log lines. The following is for tns `run android`

```
Webpack process exited with code 0 when we expected it to be long living with watch.
Error while executing action on device emulator-5554. The error is { Error: Executing webpack failed with exit code 0.
    at WebpackCompilerService.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/webpack/webpack-compiler-service.js:102:39)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/webpack/webpack-compiler-service.js:10:58)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) code: 0, deviceIdentifier: 'emulator-5554' }
Executing webpack failed with exit code 0.
```

Running `tns build android` yields:

```
15:35:35.828 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient] Received result Success[value=org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildActionResult@79d8407f] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=7854, address=[20952e36-f07a-456e-9283-61c96877e6d3 port:39999, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1588854861253, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=897270b3-048d-4379-9e18-2b62285c66ff,javaHome=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_211,daemonRegistryDir=/home/jesse/.gradle/daemon,pid=7854,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=-Xmx16384M,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).
15:35:35.829 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Finished
15:35:35.829 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: connection stop
Command ./gradlew failed with exit code 1
Error: Command ./gradlew failed with exit code 1
    at Errors.failWithOptions (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/errors.js:147:28)
    at Errors.fail (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/errors.js:120:21)
    at GradleCommandService.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/android/gradle-command-service.js:35:30)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/android/gradle-command-service.js:5:65)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Interestingly the debug log says "Received result Success" and "build should be done", but still gradlew fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a bug in the package nativescript-worker-loader@0.11. For now, the package needs to be downgraded to v0.10 and it will work.

Thanks to [NathanaelA](https://github.com/NathanaelA) for the [answer](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-sqlite/issues/161)!

For those interested, here's [an issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/worker-loader/issues/58) regarding the problem, which already has a pending PR submitted by NathanaelA.