# Getting compilation error when running native script application

Tags: angular, webpack, nativescript, node-modules, package.json

Getting this compile error when run the native script application.

[image: Click here to see error image]

Having the compile error as "Executing webpack failed with exit code 0".
I'm migrating my native script application which was running fine.
Upgraded my node version to 17.3.1 and native script version to 8.1.5.

my package.json

```js
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "com.abcd.abcd",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "5.3.1"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "5.3.1"
    }
  },
  "description": " Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "~7.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "~7.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.0.4",
    "@angular/http": "~7.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "~7.0.4",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "^5.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "nativescript-accordion": "^6.0.0-beta.2",
    "nativescript-angular": "~7.0.3",
    "nativescript-checkbox": "^3.0.3",
    "nativescript-drop-down": "^4.0.1",
    "nativescript-feedback": "^1.3.9",
    "nativescript-geolocation": "^5.1.0",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "^1.3.0",
    "nativescript-loading-indicator": "^2.4.0",
    "nativescript-ng-ripple": "^2.0.1",
    "nativescript-phone": "^1.4.0",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^7.3.0",
    "nativescript-ratings": "^1.0.1",
    "nativescript-screen-orientation": "^1.0.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "^7.1.0",
    "nativescript-worker-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "nativescript-youtubeplayer": "^3.0.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tns-core-modules": "^5.2.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.0.4",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "~0.4.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~7.0.4",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.7.9",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~0.21.0",
    "tns-android": "5.3.1",
    "tns-platform-declarations": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

Kindly help me with the solution...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60967636/how-to-debug-webpack-executing-webpack-failed-with-exit-code-0-in-nativescript